# Want to upload call recordings on firebase but isn't happening

Tags: android

I want to upload my recordings automatically on firebase,for that I have provided the path where they are stored. In logs the path is shown, but when same path is passed to uri, it's saying:   "could not locate file for uploading
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response"

Here's screenshot of the debugging app :
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sUD9.png

Here's code of recorderservice class :

```
    public class RecorderService extends Service {


    MediaRecorder recorder;
    static final String TAGS = " Inside Service";
    private StorageReference mstorage;
    private String filen = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //filen = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       //filen = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My Records/";
        //filen = "recorded_audio.3gp";
        mstorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();

        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("number");
        Log.d(TAGS, "Phone number in service: " + phoneNumber);

        String time = new CommonMethods().getTIme();
        String path = new CommonMethods().getPath();
        String rec = path + "/" + phoneNumber + "_" + time + ".mp4";

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

        recorder.setOutputFile(rec);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();

        Log.d(TAGS, "onStartCommand: " + "Recording started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
               //uploadAudio();
        super.onDestroy();

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        Log.d(TAGS, "onDestroy: " + "Recording stopped");
          uploadAudio();
    }

    private void uploadAudio() {
        //String path = new CommonMethods().getPath();
        //String rec = path ;
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My Records/");
        String path=file.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d(TAGS,"uploadAudio:" + file);
        Log.d(TAGS,"lets see:" + path);
        //Log.d(TAGS,"wecandoit:" +rec);
        StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("Audio").child("new_audio.3gp"); // change it to give name of recording
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"uploading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //Log.d(TAGS,"uploadAudio:"+ rec);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with storage rules change it to

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
}
}
```

Comment: No. it's the fact that he's passing it a directory instead of a file.

Comment: you are right he is passing the path instead of the file

Comment: @LinuxMasterRace then how to pass file path, do let me know it would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//Call this wherever you want to start recording.
  recordAudio("/TestRecording.mp4");

  public void recordAudio(String fileName) {
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, fileName);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)+"/"+fileName);
    recorder.setOutputFile(file);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final android.app.ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new android.app.ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Recording");
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_NORMAL);
    mProgressDialog.setButton("Stop recording", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("Audio").child("new_audio.mp4");
            ///UPLOAD HERE

    mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface p1) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
        }
    });
    recorder.start();
    mProgressDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Nah, this is not working. How can you pass a file type into string type parameter. Also where path variable should be defined do specify.

Comment: That was sudo code. you need to pass file back from  onStartCommand to upload audio. i'll give you a working example and let you figure out

Comment: will this upload recordings on firebase ?

Comment: it should. try it and let me know.

Comment: @LinuxMasterRace sudo code is something else, I think you mean pseudocode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode